# How to use Scala enums for JOOQ converters

Tags: scala, enums, jooq

I found in documentation how to force type from value to Java enum by [EnumConverter](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/EnumConverter.html).
I tried to make my own converter for scalas enum. Enum:

```scala
package com.enums

object BlockSize extends Enumeration {
  type BlockSize = Value

  val Small, Medium, Large, Wide = Value
}
```

Converter:

```scala
package com.converters

import com.jooqdb.enums.BlockSize
import com.jooqdb.enums.enums.BlockSize.BlockSize
import org.jooq.Converter

class BlockSizeConverter extends Converter[String, BlockSize] {
  override def from(databaseObject: String): BlockSize = if(databaseObject == null) null
    else BlockSize.withName(databaseObject)

  override def to(userObject: BlockSize): String = if(userObject == null) null
    else userObject.toString

  override def fromType(): Class[String] = classOf[String]

  override def toType: Class[BlockSize] = classOf[BlockSize.Value]
}
```

Config:

```xml
<forcedType>
  <userType>scala.Enumeration.Value</userType>
  <converter>com.converters.BlockSizeConverter</converter>
  <expression>some_table.block_size</expression>
</forcedType>
```

Is it possible to bind values in JOOQ to scala enum?

UPD: compilation was successful, but `publishLoca`l failed due to scaladoc generation. Workaround by `sources in (Compile, doc) := Seq.empty`. Anyway, cannot use this code in scala

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But what's the question?

Comment: Question is how to do this, since it always leads to compile error

Comment: What's the compilation error? (I'm assuming you're referencing the wrong user type, but might be something else, too)